# Pandas: find all unique values in one column and normalize all values in another column to their last value

Tags: python, pandas

### **Problem**

> I want to find all unique values in one column and normalize the
>   corresponding values in another column to its last value. I want to achieve this via the **pandas** module using **python3**.

***Example:***

**Original dataset**

```
Fruit   | Amount
Orange  |     90
Orange  |     80
Orange  |     10
Apple   |    100
Apple   |     50
Orange  |     20
Orange  |     60   --> latest value of Orange. Use to normalize Orange
Apple   |     75
Apple   |     25
Apple   |     40   --> latest value of Apple. Used to normalize Apple
```

**Desired output**

Ratio column with normalized values for unique values in the 'Fruit' column

```
Fruit   | Amount |  Ratio
Orange  |     90 |  90/60 --> 150%  
Orange  |     80 |  80/60 --> 133.3%
Orange  |     10 |  10/60 --> 16.7%
Apple   |    100 | 100/40 --> 250%
Apple   |     50 |  50/40 --> 125%
Orange  |     20 |  20/60 --> 33.3%
Orange  |     60 |  60/60 --> 100%
Apple   |     75 |  75/40 --> 187.5%
Apple   |     25 |  25/40 --> 62.5%
Apple   |     40 |  40/40 --> 100%
```

**Python code attempt**

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r'C:\fruitdata.dat'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|')
print(df)
print(df.loc[df['Fruit   '] == 'Orange  '])
print(df[df['Fruit   '] == 'Orange  '].tail(1))
```

**Python output (IPython)**

```
In [1]: df
   Fruit      Amount
0  Orange         90
1  Orange         80
2  Orange         10
3  Apple         100
4  Apple          50
5  Orange         20
6  Orange         60
7  Apple          75
8  Apple          25
9  Apple          40

In [2]: df.loc[df['Fruit   '] == 'Orange  ']
   Fruit      Amount
0  Orange         90
1  Orange         80
2  Orange         10
5  Orange         20
6  Orange         60

In [3]: df[df['Fruit   '] == 'Orange  '].tail(1)
Out[3]: 
   Fruit      Amount
6  Orange         60
```

**Question**

> How can I loop through each unique item in 'Fruit' and normalize all values against its
>   tail value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `iloc` with `groupby`

```
df.groupby('Fruit').Amount.apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[-1])
Out[38]: 
0    1.500000
1    1.333333
2    0.166667
3    2.500000
4    1.250000
5    0.333333
6    1.000000
7    1.875000
8    0.625000
9    1.000000
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

After assign it back

```
df['New']=df.groupby('Fruit').Amount.apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[-1])
df
Out[40]: 
    Fruit  Amount       New
0  Orange      90  1.500000
1  Orange      80  1.333333
2  Orange      10  0.166667
3   Apple     100  2.500000
4   Apple      50  1.250000
5  Orange      20  0.333333
6  Orange      60  1.000000
7   Apple      75  1.875000
8   Apple      25  0.625000
9   Apple      40  1.000000
```

Without using `lambda`

```
df.Amount/df.groupby('Fruit',sort=False).Amount.transform('last')
Out[46]: 
0    1.500000
1    1.333333
2    0.166667
3    2.500000
4    1.250000
5    0.333333
6    1.000000
7    1.875000
8    0.625000
9    1.000000
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Amazing! Do you know if I can achieve the same without a lambda?

Comment: @JodyK let me provide

Comment: two great solutions! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JodyK if it work for you do not forget to accept it